# Why are my posts not getting published after using git push?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

A complete dummy here...

So, we have a website hosted on Github, and we used Jekyll. Now, everything was working just fine, however, a couple of days ago after pushing new posts we get nothing on the website...

Usually, we do it as following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push
```

And everything works fine.

After running git status, this is what we get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

We got the same message before, so the only change is basically that the posts are not showing up on the website :(

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a chance you have committed and pushed on a branch other than master?
I suggest doing `git branch -r` to see the existing remote branches. Also check your commit history with `git log`.

Comment: Hey @Karen, no :( I see a bunch of branches, and this one (`origin/HEAD -> origin/master`) is colored differently. `Git log` comes up with bunch of logs, latest being: `commit 099f1d078a3970800d9a7ec8a5512f58ffa8f290 
(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)

Author: Amos Z <myemail@gmail.com>

Date:   Fri Jun 10 09:43:35 2022 +0200`

Comment: when you say website, you mean the remote git repository right?

Comment: Technically `origin/master` is not a *branch* name, it's a *remote-tracking name* (or what Git calls a *remote-tracking branch name* with the word "branch" being put in there just to confuse people ). That's your repository's memory of some *other* repository's *branch* name `master`: in this case, you have a repository on your own machine (your "laptop", let's call this), and a second nearly-identical repository on GitHub. There may be many more copies: Git is a *distributed* version control system and it works by letting everyone have as many copies as they want.

Comment: In any case, what you're doing is normal: you make a new commit on your laptop, which goes into *your* `master` branch. Then you run `git push origin master` and your laptop Git software calls up GitHub's Git software. These two Git implementations (which are different software but speak the same protocol) figure out which commits you have that they don't—that's the one you just added, in this case—and your `git push` sends those commits (that commit) to their Git software to put in their repo, and then has them make their name `master` remember that new commit.

Comment: That part is working. What's *not* working is that, having made that new commit *appear on GitHub*, there's some third-party software—Jekyll—that's supposed to fire up, read your new commit, *transform* it into a usable set of web pages, and then send those web pages somewhere (to some web hosting site, perhaps GitHub Pages). That's the part you need to debug. Look at the pop-up info for the [tag:jekyll] tag for hints on this process.

Comment: Thank you all, what a beautiful community! Might start some coding courses :D Once again, thank you for clearing it out for me!

Comment: you can check the build & deploy log for any errors. if you're deploying using GitHub Pages (common with Jekyll) go to your repo on github.com, click "commits", then a red X next to the newest commit and look for an error message

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced a similar issue. New posts were no more shown on my GitHub web site. I create posts locally and push them to GitHub using Visual Studio Code. Fixed my issue by making "encoding: UTF-8" uppercase in "_config.yml" file (was "encoding: utf-8" before). Once this change was pushed, new posts were shown correctly.

Update: recently noticed as well that timestamp of posts may be the reason for them to not show up. Will need to check which timezone is applied to GitHub web site and compare it with my own.